# How to search within the structure and display it

Tags: c, arrays, search, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct PCSpec{
    int ComputerID;
    char ComputerName[50];
    float Price;
};


void PrintAll(int count,struct PCSpec Computer[100]);
int InputData(int count,struct PCSpec Computer[100]);
void Search(int count,struct PCSpec Computer[100]);
void SearchID(int count,struct PCSpec Computer[100]);
void SearchNAME(int count,struct PCSpec Computer[100]);
void MainMenu(int count,struct PCSpec Computer[100]);
void Option1Menu();
void Option2Menu();
void PrintSelective(struct PCSpec Computer[100]);

main()
{
int count;
struct PCSpec Computer[100];
printf("Please enter the Number Of Computer (Max is 100) ");
scanf("%d",&count);
system("cls");
Option1Menu();
MainMenu(count,Computer);
}

int InputData(int count,struct PCSpec Computer[100])
{
 int i;
 for(i=0;i<count;i++)
{
    printf("Enter the ComputerID = ");
    scanf("%d", &Computer[i].ComputerID);
    printf("Enter the ComputerName, Maximum 50 Characters = ");
    scanf(" %s",Computer[i].ComputerName);
    }
printf("Data was SUCCESSFULLY recorded!");
}

void MainMenu(int count,struct PCSpec Computer[100])
{
while (1)
{
    int option;
    printf("\nEnter your choice : ");
    scanf("%d", &option);
    switch (option)
    {
    case 1:    
        system("cls");
        InputData(count,Computer);
        system("cls");
        Option1Menu();
        break;
    case 2:
        system("cls");    
        PrintAll(count,Computer);
        Option1Menu();
        break;
    case 3:
        system("cls");
        Search(count,Computer);
    case 4: 
        exit(0);
       }
    }
}


void Search(int count,struct PCSpec Computer[100])
{
int Option;
Option2Menu();
while(1)
{
    printf("\nEnter your choice : ");
    scanf("%d",&Option);
    switch(Option)
    {
        case 1:
            system("cls");
            SearchID(count,Computer);
            Option2Menu();
            break;
        case 2:
            system("cls");
            SearchNAME(count,Computer);
            Option2Menu();
            break;
        case 3:
            system("cls");
            MainMenu(count,Computer);
        case 4:
            exit(1);
    }
 }
}
```

Sorry for the long Code, the section below is the one that i'm having problem. I'm able to search successfully but i'm unable to display the searched structure. My initial plan was to search the ComputerID, and if it's found, i want it to display the ComputerName as well.

The output that i wanted to get if the ID is found.
Computer ID =  21
Computer Name = Desktop

```
void SearchID(int count,struct PCSpec Computer[100])
{
int i,id;
printf("Please Enter Computer ID ");
scanf("%d",&id);
for(i=0;i<count;i++)
{
if(Computer[i].ComputerID == id)
    {
    printf("%d is found at %d",id,i);   
    //PrintSelective(Computer);           
    break;
    }
}
if( i == count )
printf("Unable to locate ComputerID\n");
}
```

For this section, my intention is the same as the previous section, but this time i wanted to search the ComputerName, and is found it will print the ComputerID as well.

Right now the problem that i faced is, the input i enter cannot be found.

```
void SearchNAME(int count,struct PCSpec Computer[100])
{
int j;
char NAME;
printf("Warning CASE Senstitive!\n");
printf("Please Enter Computer Name ");
scanf("%s",&NAME);
for(j=0;j<count;j++)
{
if(Computer[j].ComputerName == "NAME")
    {
    printf("%s is found at %d",NAME,j); 
    //PrintSelective(Computer);
    break;
    }
}
if( j == count )
printf("Unable to locate ComputerID\n");
}
```

The rest pretty much the declaration

```
void PrintAll(int count,struct PCSpec Computer[100])
{
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<count;j++)
    {
    printf("Computer Package %d\n", j);
    printf("Computer ID = \t\t%d\n",Computer[j].ComputerID);
    printf("Computer Name = \t%s\n",Computer[j].ComputerName);
    }
}

void PrintSelective(struct PCSpec Computer[100])
{
int i;
printf("Computer Package %d\n", i);
printf("Computer ID = \t\t%d\n",Computer[i].ComputerID);
printf("Computer Name = \t%s\n",Computer[i].ComputerName);
}

void Option1Menu()
{
    printf("\n1] Create a Record\n");
    printf("2] Display Records\n");
    printf("3] Search a Record\n");
    printf("4] Exit");
}

void Option2Menu()
{
    printf("\n1] Search using ComputerID\n");
    printf("2] Search using ComputerNAME\n");
    printf("3] Back to Main Menu\n");
    printf("4] Exit the Program\n");
}
```

Sorry for my previous post which my question is unclear, as i'm still new in C all feedback toward my coding is appreciated! And another thing is, Which compiler did you guys used? or Standard for C so that other won't have any issue when compiling the code i wrote.

Comment: `Computer[j].ComputerName == "NAME"` won't work. You need `strcmp` to compare strings in C.

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

1. With `scanf("%s",&NAME)` you read a *string* into a *single character*. Non-empty strings always needs at least two characters: At least one for the string contents *plus* one for the string terminator. A string of 49 characters needs an *array* of 50 `char`.
2. `"NAME"` is a *literal string* and not the variable `NAME`
3. With `Computer[j].ComputerName == "NAME"` you are comparing two pointers. With `Computer[j].ComputerName == NAME` you will be comparing a pointer to a single `char` value. If you change `NAME` to be an array, then again you are comparing two pointers. To compare strings you need to use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp).

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `i` into `PrintSelective`:

```
void PrintSelective(struct PCSpec Computer[100], int i)
{
    printf("Computer Package %d\n", i);
    printf("Computer ID = \t\t%d\n",Computer[i].ComputerID);
    printf("Computer Name = \t%s\n",Computer[i].ComputerName);
}
```

and then call it as:

```
    PrintSelective(Computer, i);
```

`PrintAll` should call `PrintSelective` too.

Alternatively, I wouldn't print the index in `PrintSelective`, in which case, write as:

```
void PrintSelective(struct PCSpec *pComputer)
{
    printf("Computer ID = \t\t%d\n",pComputer->ComputerID);
    printf("Computer Name = \t%s\n",pComputer->ComputerName);
}
```

and call as:

```
    PrintSelective(&Computer[i]);
```